# jquery select2 search does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am getting data from mysql with ajax request how ever i have managed to do that. and data is loading perfectly in drop down, but when ever i try to use the search it does not work. i have checked out many posts on stack related to this problem but i can't find any thing to fix this problem any help

**HTML**

```
<select class="" name="directory_id" id="Se" style="width: 50%"></select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#Se').select2(
{
    ajax: 
    {
        dataType: "json",
        url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>project/get_subs_dirs",
        processResults: function (data) 
        {
            return 
            {
                results: $.map(data, function(obj) 
                {
                    return { id: obj.id, text: obj.dir_name };
                })
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Your jQuery will need `<script>` and `</script>` tags. Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: i have open and end script tags